# Result of k_clique_communities

Tags: python, networkx

There is a function in networkX called k_clique_communities that find k-clique communities in graph, and I run the code on my data.

```
K5 = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G,first_label=2)
G.add_edges_from(K5.edges())
c = list(nx.k_clique_communities(G, 4))
list(c[9])
[145, 276, 277, 278, 279, 138]
list(c[10])
[353, 146, 244, 198, 327, 252]
```

I am confused about the result here.

What does list(c[9]) mean?

What's the difference between list(c[9]) and list(c[10])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for k_clique_communties](http://chebee7i-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities.html) says that

> A k-clique community is the union of all cliques of size k that can be reached through adjacent (sharing k-1 nodes) k-cliques.

Now each individual list item will a collection of (union of) k-sized cliques thatw each other and shared (k-1) nodes. In your case `c[9]` returns

```
[145, 276, 277, 278, 279, 138]
```

So this is a union of 4-sized cliques that were adjacent to other and share 3 nodes with each other. You can visualize these only these nodes from your graph and then you will see that these were adjacent cliques sharing 3 nodes with each other.

Now to the next part, `c[0]` and `c[1]` are nothing but individual list of such union of k-cliques with the properties described above, i.e. it might be the case that there must have multiple union of 4 sized cliques which share 3 nodes in your graph, so you can access the first union at `c[0]`, next at `c[1]` and so on

Answer (score -1):

`list(c[0])` means that `c` is a list, you are taking the object at index 0, and attempting to initialize a new `list` with its contents. The difference between `c[0]` and `c[10]` is that they are different elements in the list `c`. If you are confused about types, a helpful tip is to throw in a `print(type(x))` statement. `print(type(c))`, in this case, would give you `<type 'list'>`. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) is the doc page on lists for more help getting started.